# View function is not being called after submitting form in django

Tags: python, django

I have made a simple form inside a html file whose path is **www.site.com/posts/5**. Whenever the form is submitted, it redirects back to the same page i.e **www.site.com/posts/5** displaying a message given by user in the form.

However, whenever the form is submitted it doesn't call the `foobar` view.

The urls.py, views.py and html files are as follows:-

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('posts/<int:foo>',user_views.display, name="display",
path('posts/<int:foo>',user_views.foobar, name="makefoo"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def foobar(request, foo):
    #do something
```

**html file**

```
<form name="fooform" action= "{% url 'makefoo' 5 %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="FOO_BODY" maxlength="300" required>
    <input type="submit" value="comment">
    <input type="reset" value="clear">
</form>
```

Edit : `user_views` is just `from user import views as user_views`

Comment: You here have two `path(..)`s with *exactly the same "pattern". So it will typically pick the first one.

Comment: But shouldn't it called the second one as I am referencing it directly by the name?

Comment: no, since you here *generate a URL*, the parameters itself are lost, so in case it is not a bijective function, then this will result in problems. After all `{% url ... %}` just generates something like `/posts/5`, so there is no way to determinate what the original name was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not attach two views to the *same* URL. The `{% url ... %}` template tag, only *generates* a URL for that path. But if there is a "*url clash*", then it is possible that the requests ends up in the other view.

You thus should define another URL, or encode the `post` logic in the `display` view. In case of a `POST` request, you can thus first take the necessary steps, and then for example return a redirect to the page, such that we can again render the page:

```
def display(request, foo):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do something
        return redirect(display, foo=foo)
    #do something else (original code)
    return HttpResponse(..)
```

This is the famous [*Post/Redirect/Get* web development design pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This is usually better than returning a HTTP response directly in the POST, since if the user performs a refresh, the POST will be performed a *second* time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @williem, you have two path() defined in the urls.py.

Always First matching route will be picked up from the url route table. So whenever r^'posts/' is requested it will call the display() from the user_views, so it will never go to foobar(). Either remove the route with display() or change the sequence. Also, I assume you imported the user_views.

Reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Ah, yes. I imported the user_views. Forgot to mention it in the post. Thanks for pointing out.